# CS50 pset2 substitution

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, cs50, c-strings

The challenge is to create a program where you input a key which is a 26 character long string that is supposed to basically replace the alphabet. So for instance if you make your key "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm" it will use q for a, w for b, e for c, r for d, etc. You then enter a string which is your message, and it converts the plaintext into ciphertext.

So far in the course we have not yet covered pointers, so I imagine one should be able to complete this challenge without using * or & to reference a pointer. Instead we are told to use libraries which allow us to work with "strings" while the library deals with the technical legwork of using pointers for us in the background. I'm a bit confused by this though, because the code I originally tried was this:

```
    {
        if(isupper(plainText[i]))
        {
            cypherText[i] = key[plainText[i] - 'A'];
        }
        else if (islower(plainText[i]))
        {
            cypherText[i] = key[plainText[i] - 'a'];
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", cypherText);
```

but I was getting the following errors:

```
error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'string' (aka 'char *') from 'char'; take the address with & [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
            cypherText[i] = key[plainText[i] - 'A'];
                          ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                            &
error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'string' (aka 'char *') from 'char'; take the address with & [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
            cypherText[i] = key[plainText[i] - 'a'];
                          ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                            &
error: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'string *' (aka 'char **') [-Werror,-Wformat]
    printf("%s\n", cypherText);
```

so I changed the code to the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    string key;
    do
    {
        key = get_string("Key:");
    }
    while(strlen(key) != 26);

    string plainText = get_string("Text:");
    string cypherText[strlen(plainText)];

    for (int i = 0; plainText[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(isupper(plainText[i]))
        {
            cypherText[i] = &key[plainText[i] - 'A'];
        }
        else if (islower(plainText[i]))
        {
            cypherText[i] = &key[plainText[i] - 'a'];
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", *cypherText);
}
```

And now it compiles but does not work as expected, and the bug is not something I have been able to identify by debugging. Basically when I run it with the key "bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza" (the alphabet left shifted one letter) and then I use a message like "hello" I will get the output "ijklmnopqrstuvwxyza" which starts with the correct letter but then just continues to parse the alphabet inexplicably to me. Even if I just write a one letter long message the cyphertext will print as multiple characters.

So my questions are:

is my assumption correct that there a way to complete this challenge without using pointers, and if so, how can I correct those error messages without using & or * ?

and what is causing this weird trailing alphabet behaviour when I do use & and *?

Thank you.

Comment: `string cypherText[strlen(plainText)];` declares an array of `string` where you want an array of `char`. If you plan to use that array of `char` as a `string` like in your last line of code, remember to allocate an extra character and assign `0` to it to terminate the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining an array of strings in `string cypherText[strlen(plainText)];`, so the initial errors are due to trying to assign a string (otherwise known as char*) to a string array (aka char**), therefore:

```
error: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'string *' (aka 'char **') [-Werror,-Wformat]
    printf("%s\n", cypherText);
```

when you did

```
        if(isupper(plainText[i]))
        {
            cypherText[i] = &key[plainText[i] - 'A'];
        }
        else if (islower(plainText[i]))
        {
            cypherText[i] = &key[plainText[i] - 'a'];
        }
```

you're manipulating where the pointer cypherText is pointing to, you are effectively assigning cypherText[0][0] to start at `&key[plainText[i] - 'a']` which in your test case was the letter 'i'. each increment of i changes the row of your cypherText array, so cypherText[1][0] would be pointing to the letter 'f', **but crucially it is the same memory as allocated to your `key`.**

When you `printf("%s\n", *cypherText);`, you're asking to print out a string, and `*cypherText` is the start of your string array, so the program happily prints out the first string, which you earlier assigned as the same as `key`, but starting at the letter 'i' instead. It reads this string until '\0' is reached and happily calls it a day.